# HQL query to replace an existing file from database using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql

**I have an existing file in database and now I need to replace that from the database with a new file. what would be the HQL query to remove the existing file and add the new one?**

Comment: Just to clarify - the file is part of an entity (or is an entity itself) that is managed by Hibernate?

Comment: I have taken the file from the JSF page using the <inputfile> tag. My managedBean class saved it as a 'part' file which was converted to byte stream and then persisted to the database. Now i want to replace the already uploaded file with a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void addReplacementFile(UploadReplacementFileBean uploadReplacementFileBean) throws Exception {

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.createSessionFactory();
    Session session = null;
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();


    InputStream input = uploadReplacementFileBean.getFileData().getInputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
    for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;)
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);


    try {

        output.flush();
        String qs="update UploadFileEntity set fileData=? where  fileId=?";

        Query query=session.createQuery(qs);
        query.setParameter(0, output.toByteArray());
        query.setParameter(1, uploadReplacementFileBean.getFileId());

        query.executeUpdate();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();


    }
```

Comment: Instead of trying to update the database with HQL, retrieve the persisted UploadFileEntity and update it with the newly uploaded data.

Comment: In that case I will have to populate the object again with the values right?